# Viewing a .srf (Steinberg Resource File) on a Linux system

Tags: linux, video, fedora, video-playback

I have a Samsung Smart TV that for each recording done using its built-in recorder produces 6 different files with the following extensions each: `.cip`, `.inf`, `.mdb`, `.mta`, `.srf`, and `.ss`. The `.srf` file is by far the largest in most (if not all) recordings, so I assume that's the one that actually contains the video. It can be multiple gigabytes, whereas the others at most are a few megabytes.

From my quick research I found that `.srf` is an ambiguous file extension, but according to [this article](https://www.lifewire.com/srf-file-2622355) on Lifewire it is most likely a Steinberg Resource File as it comes from a Samsung Smart TV.

GNOME's filepicker detects it as a "Sony SRF raw image" and thus suggests I open it in Krita (a drawing program), and when I instead manually tell it to open in VLC and Totem/GNOME Videos nothing loads in neither player.

Is there any way for me to playback this type of file from my PC running Fedora 31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there any way to playback a `.srf` file from my PC running Fedora 31?

The Samsung Smart TV `.srf` format is encrypted (even if the source is a Free to Air channel). The key is stored in an MDB file with the same name.

Source: [Editing recordings from samsung Smart TV (SRF format) - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/44572-editing-recordings-samsung-smart-tv-srf-format.html)

You can use `drmdecrypt` (GNU General Public License v2.0) to decrypt them:

> drmdecrypt is a tool to decrypt PVR recordings from Samsung TVs into standard transport stream format. There are multiple similar versions out there based on code from SamyGO and various people but they are all either slow, Windows specific, full of bugs or even all together.
>
> This version is fast, POSIX compliant (Linux, FreeBSD, OSX, Windows (MinGW)) and is focused on a small number of useful features.

Source: [decke/drmdecrypt: DRM decrypting tool for Samsung TVs PVR](https://github.com/decke/drmdecrypt)